# Remove object tag but leave embed

Tags: php, object, embed

I want have some videos like this:

```
<object style="display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;" width="550" height="350" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/DlK5N-Lcvjc" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="never" /><param name="allowNetworking" value="internal" />
```

And I want to remove everything except `<embed>` tag. Also around the video there is more content which I want to keep.

I was trying to make this with `preg_replace` but it didn`t work.

Comment: Please rephrase your question and clarify. You mention embed tags, but they are nowhere in your question or in your example code.

Answer (score 2):

Use strip_tags(), it accepts as optional parameter an array with tags that should not be removed.

```
strip_tags($str,'<embed>');
```